# Apache, Tomcat : Load-balancing not using common session ID's

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, cometd

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which is deployed on 2 Tomcat instance's. Load-balancing and fail-over is achieved by an Apache instance in front using `mod_jk`. Right now, all is working well, except our PUSH technology.

PUSH technology we use is Cometd based(Bayeux API specs), and if I login, then I am logged into one server, but I cannot see users who are logged into second server online. I am using `sticky sessions` already. I thought they are responsible for managing this.

Apache configuration :

workers.properties :

```
worker.list=loadbalancer
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true

worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status

worker.server1.port=8010
worker.server1.host=localhost
worker.server1.lbfactor=1
worker.server1.type=ajp13


worker.server2.port=8011
worker.server2.host=localhost
worker.server2.type=ajp13
worker.server2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=server1,server2

worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=true
worker.myworker.sticky_session_force=True
```

sites-enabled/000-default

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com domain.com
JkMount /* loadbalancer
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/path/to/.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home//path/to/.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/path/to/.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf :

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile   /etc/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkMount /* loadbalancer
```

Tomcat only has one change, i.e jvmRoute. If necessary, I can add that. Kindly let me know why this might be happening and how to fix it. Thanks a lot. :-)

TomcatFirst' server.xml :

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Connector port="8443" enableLookups="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" 
compression="off" sslProtocols="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2" 
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" 
compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="/path/to/.keystore" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"/>
 <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server1">
<Host name="www.domain.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Alias>domain.com</Alias>
</Engine>
```

TomcatSecond's server.xml :

```
 <Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Connector port="8444" enableLookups="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" 
    compression="off" sslProtocols="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2" 
    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" 
    compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
    keystoreFile="/path/to/.keystore" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"/>
     <Connector port="8011" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8444" URIEncoding="utf-8"
     compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
    />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server2">
    <Host name="www.domain.com"  appBase="webapps"
                unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

            <Alias>domain.com</Alias>
    </Engine>
```

*Edit*

Just discovered a new element to add in web.xml as [distributable](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.Distributable) . Will this help? Trying out takes 2 deployments, that's why I thought I might ask.

Comment: @stefan : server.xml added. Kindly have a look.. :-)

Comment: Yes you need the "distributable" flag in web.xml as well as the cluster element in server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the workers file like this?

```
worker.list=loadbalancer,jk-status

worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true

worker.server1.port=8010
worker.server1.host=localhost
worker.server1.lbfactor=1
worker.server1.type=ajp13

worker.server2.port=8011
worker.server2.host=localhost
worker.server2.type=ajp13
worker.server2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=true
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=server1,server2
```

JvmRoute is set correctly, but I cannot find a cluster element in your server.xml files (engine or host level)?

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
```

You might want to disable the ssl connectors in the Tomcats and enable it in your webserver?

The mapping should look like:

```
JkMount /appName     loadbalancer
JkMount /appName/*   loadbalancer

JkMount /jkStatus    jk-status
```

Check http://example.com/jkstatus to see it the nodes did find each other.

Once the cluster is set up and the DeltaManager (spreading your sessions) is working, the session Ids will have the node name as suffix: ANYSESSIONID.server1

Comment: What is the appName parameter here? I have jkmount  /* loadbalancer. That doesn't cut it?

Comment: Update : After I restarted all of them again, now it seems to work. I tested with 4 colleagues. I will see again today if there is some problem, if not, I will accept your answer. Thank you.. :-)

Comment: Hi Stefan, I am sorry to report, but the solution you gave didn't work. In the evening we tested it again, with colleagues in different locations, some of them were accumulated in 2nd server, while some on 1st. Neither could see each other. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions stefan? Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "see each other"?

Comment: Meaning. If there are 5 users, user1,2,3,4,5. When u1,u2 login on first-server, they can only see opposite person online in chat even though u3,u4,u5 are logged in into 3rd server. They are not seen online in chat by u1 or u2 and vice-versa.